# customizing shibboleth and JOSSO

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth, josso

I am looking for an SSO solution that can be customized according to our needs.
From what i saw over the internet it seems that Shibboleth and JOSSO are solutions that just need to be installed and configured. My question is to what extent can they be customized to use with web apps.Please consider following points.

1. control over cookies and session management
2. integration with existing authentication mechanisms being used for the app (e.g. two factor authentication)
3. collection of data from the user at the time of registration.

Suggestions on any other frameworks and approaches are welcome

Comment: As a shibboleth user (not maintainer) I can tell you that this software is a pain in the %$! as it is really hard to set up. We struggled with this for several weeks. If you only need basic authentification, you might want to look for something else.

Comment: my requirement is to customize it..to a great extent..